# Prevent SAP ICF from terminating execution when client disconnects

Tags: asynchronous, connection, abap, saprfc

We are working on an SAP ICF Service (HTTP), which allows mobile devices to call function modules via an XML interface.
The given XML contains data about what function module to be called and what parameters have to be used.
Whenever the function module finishes, the result is sent back to the mobile device. We are using an `IF_HTTP_EXTENSION` handler.

The issue is, that, whenever the function module takes a long time to run, the mobile device runs into a timeout and then closes the connection, re-connects and re-sends the request.
Whenever this happens, the `handle_request` method of the `IF_HTTP_EXTENSION` handler immediately terminates.
But we need to continue the execution of the called function, as the client resends the request with the same sequence number.
So we do not call the actual function twice, but a "waiting"-method, which waits for the previously invoked function to complete.
We do this by checking the database on a regular basis (`WHILE` loop with `WAIT UP TO 2 SECONDS` in each iteration).

As long as the client does not timeout, we want to send the response as soon as possible.
Therefore in the first request it is not appropriate to do a while loop with 2 seconds delay.

Our current approach is the following (in `handle_request`):

```
CALL FUNCTION 'CLIENT_DESIRED_FUNCTION'
    STARTING NEW TASK l_client_id
    CALLING processing_finished ON END OF TASK
    EXPORTING
        ...
```

After this, we wait for its completion by:

```
WAIT UNTIL a_running <> 'X'.
```

But, as soon as the client disconnects, the called function (and the `handle_request` method as well) terminates.

When we remove the `CALLING processing_finished ON END OF TASK`, the function actually continues!
This is our desired behavior. However, now, there is no way to wait for the function to complete, as the `WAIT UNTIL` statement returns with `sy-subrc = 4` (No async rfc function calls).

We could just use a simple `WHILE`-`WAIT UP TO 2 SECONDS`-loop, but then we have the delay, which we really want to prevent.
Another solution we thought about, was to send an HTTP Code 102 to the client, just before the timeout occurs. But this is not a good solution, as the mobile device could be without network and then does not receive the 102 in time.

Is there a way to prevent SAP ICF from terminating the `handle_request` method OR is it possible to efficiently wait for the async task without using the `CALLING ... ON END OF TASK` parameter?

Kind regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code at hand, but I have solved this issue before when SAP Gateway wasn't around and you had to build your own REST services.

I used a timeout for the processing of 2 seconds. After that time, the server must reply with something. If the processing isn't finished (using the async function module), the server responds with HTTP Status 202 Accepted. The client may then send another request at a later time, asking for status of the previous request.

This pattern worked very well. The frontend developer used a async model for all requests, creating an application that never had delays even if response times in SAP did vary. As an example, committing a Sales Order during peak hours could take 1 to 15 seconds.

Comment: This was our first solution. Unfortunately, just sending an "i am doing something" - message to the mobile device does not work, as the client could be without network and therfore does not receive this message and still closes the connection. We know, that a customer, who wants to use our technique, has bad wifi coverage.

The users do not have to wait, as the clients can send those requests asynchronously, like you also proposed :-).

Thanks for your suggestion, but this does not work in our case, due to the connection behvior of the mobile devices. :-(

Comment: Every time the client send a request to the server, it will receive a reply instantly. The reply will say 201 Accepted - presented to the client as "We have received your request and will start processing. Please check back later.". Whenever the client connects the second time is irrelevant as you can check the status of the first request. Most likely, it will be processed and a proper response can be issued. This pattern is to handle occasional disconnects and high latency clients. Typically for mobile usage.